# How to prompt when win_service service exists?

Tags: ansible, windows

I'm trying to figure out the steps needed to get when or other conditionals to react when service is present on hosts targeted on my task.

With this I get report that service is on one of the nodes but how could I trigger a shutdown for the service, reboot for *only* this server and wait until service is again running.

#### Task to run

```
  - name: Check Service by Display name | NameOfMyService
    win_service:
      name: name_of_my_service
    register: service
    ignore_unreachable: yes
  
  - name: Print status of Windows Service | NameOfMyService
    debug: 
      var: service
```

#### Output:

```
ok: [win_host] => {
    "service": {
        "can_pause_and_continue": false,
        "changed": false,
        "depended_by": [],
        "dependencies": [
            "Afd",
            "Tcpip"
        ],
        "description": "Apache/2.4.46 (Win64)",
        "desktop_interact": false,
        "display_name": "Name_of_the_service",
        "exists": true,
        "failed": false,
        "name": "Name_of_the_service",
        "path": "\"C:\\Path\\to\\service\Apache.exe\" -k runservice",
        "start_mode": "auto",
        "state": "running",
        "username": "LocalSystem"
    }
}
```

There is '"exists": true,' but how could I trigger notifier or something like that from the output.

All help appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [conditonals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html).

```
  - name: Check Service by Display name | NameOfMyService
    win_service:
      name: name_of_my_service
    register: service
    ignore_unreachable: yes
  
  - name: Print status of Windows Service | NameOfMyService
    debug: 
      var: service

  - name: Frobnicate the service
    frobnicate:
      service: name_of_my_service
    when: service.exists | default(false)
```